# Kotlin as multi platform dependency issue

Tags: java, android, kotlin, multiplatform, kotlin-extension

I am writing an experiment project for multi platform by using Kotlin. I wrote some common logic by using RXjava and retrofit.  There are three folder 
Kotlin[commonMain]
Kotlin[androidMain]
Kotlin[iosMain]

The code work fine in Kotlin[androidMain] folder. When I moved in Kotlin[commonMain], Class unable to reslove retrofit and RX libraries.

Is it because Kotlin  multi platform can not compile Rx and retrofit libs?

Or am I doing something wrong.

Please anyone can explain to me.

REgards,

```
**import okhttp3. unalbe to resolve***
**import okhttp3.Response unable to resolve**


class AuthorizationInterceptor(private val authorization: Authorization) : Interceptor{

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        var accessToken =  authorization.getCachedToken()
        val request: Request =
            chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Authorization", "%s ,  %s  , %s".format(accessToken))
                .build()
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Onik  thanks, there is one module. module has three folders /flavour. Each flavour has own dependency. Dependency in build.gradle only works for mainandroid. Not for maincommon.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. There is no variant of `retrofit` available (yet) for kotlin native. [ktor-client](https://ktor.io/clients/http-client.html) is a very good alternate though.

[This is a very nice article](https://medium.com/@champigny.florent/my-first-experience-with-kotlin-native-988e96f26657) about  a kotlin multi platform project and demonstrates `ktor-client`.

As for `RxJava`, as the name suggest, the framework is implemented for Java (and some JVM based languages) only. There are appreciable efforts in progress for kotlin-native such as [RxKotlin/ Reaktive](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin/issues/115) but nothing (widely acceptable) is production ready as yet.